# react-admin: Unable to compile <PostEdit> (Parsing Error)

Tags: react-admin

I was following [this react-admin tutorial](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html).
In **Adding Creation and Editing Capabilities** section, I was asked to copy the `<PostEdit>` and paste the code (dumped by the console) in `posts.js`.

Below is the formatted code, but after I save it will return this error [server error of PostEdit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWhMD.png)

```
import * as React from "react";
//import { List, Datagrid, TextField, ReferenceField } from 'react-admin';
import { List, Datagrid, TextField, ReferenceField, EditButton } from 'react-admin';
import {PostEdit} from 'react-admin'


export const PostList = props => (
    <List {...props}>
        <Datagrid>
        <TextField source="id" />
            <ReferenceField source="userId" reference="users">
            <TextField source="name" />
            </ReferenceField>
            
            <TextField source="title" />
           
           
            <EditButton />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);

//New Compnent copied from console
export const PostEdit = props => (
    <Edit {...props}>
        <SimpleForm>
        <TextInput disabled source="id" />
            <ReferenceInput source="userId" reference="users">
            <SelectInput optionText="name" />
            </ReferenceInput>
            
            <TextInput source="title" />
            <TextInput multiline source="body" />
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);
```

Comment: Hi, would you kindly share the entire code in your `posts.js` because the parser says that you've already defined `PostEdit` in the same scope.

Comment: Can't share the entire code as a comment because the code is over 800 characters and the comment box can't accept more than that

Comment: The best thing would be to find every line that has `<PostEdit>` and add it to the original question. And if possible comment the line number against each e.g. `export const <PostEdit> = props =>.... line.5`

Comment: Hi, would you kindly remvoe this line? `import { PostEdit } from 'react-admin'`, you code should work after that, let us know. While `js` compiler runs, and reaches this line `export const PostEdit` the compiler get confused because it already has `PostEdit` in the stack.